# Given a string I want to retrieve sections of the string based on delimiters using a cut command?

Tags: shell, cut

I have the following string:

```
MrRelatedTests/ubsr064412_01.tst,GREEN,verified skipped,lwks08,31s,1
```

I want to retrieve it into the following three subsections:

```
MrRelatedTests/ubsr064412_01.tst
GREEN,verified skipped
lwks08,31s,1
```

I have to use this stuff in a shell script. Thus if
`$string=MrRelatedTests/ubsr064412_01.tst,GREEN,verified skipped,lwks08,31s,1`    I should be able to retrieve the following

```
$a=MrRelatedTests/ubsr064412_01.tst
$b=GREEN,verified skipped
$c=lwks08,31s,1
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What do you have so far, and how doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
a=$(echo ${STR} | cut -d, -f1)
b=$(echo ${STR} | cut -d, -f2-3)
c=$(echo ${STR} | cut -d, -f4-6)
```

Comment: Thats a good one thanks. but I have another issue. for a string like  "MrRelatedTests/CRI00135453.02/DynLacSac_63.tst,YELLOW,verify skipped,lwks15,61s,1" , in place of getting "YELLOW,verify skipped" as the second variable, I am getting "YELLOW,verify" in one line and then "skipped" in the next line. if am getting the following result "MrRelatedTests/CRI00135453.02/DynLacSac_63.tst
YELLOW,verify
skipped
lwks15,61s"

Comment: The variable gets created correctly even when there is a space. What you're seeing is likely a result of a later reference to it -- in that case, just wrap double quotes around it: ``for VAR in "$a" "$b" "$c"``